# Is it possible to invoke a crontab job once in Apache php slim framework?

Tags: apache, cron, slim

I have a php script which runs as the Apache daemon user, to first remove any existing crontabs that might be already installed by the daemon user, then adding the new crontab.

I wish to evoke this only once when my PHP Slim web application loads for the first time, ideally as part of the Apache startup.

It seems that putting it anywhere in the index.php file (either directly or via a require file) doesn't prevent the crontab script from being constantly reloaded. I've tried using `$GLOBAL` with an `if` statement, which unfortunately I haven't been able to formulate a working solution, however there must be something more rudimentary which allows me to invoke a php script just once after Apache has been restarted?

Ideally I'd rather not modify the Apache startup script since I wish to keep everything within the slim web application itself (for source control purposes).

Comment: don't do it via a web-accessible script. modify the system scripts that start up apache and put the commands there. e.g. /etc/init.d/httpd or whatever it would be on your particular os.

Comment: I just modified my original question to try to avoid this solution, is there any way I can do this as part of the application itself? Also, by 'web-accessible' the user will never see the script, or be able to invoke it manually (or at least, shouldn't be able to).

Comment: not really. anythign you do in slim would be pointless. you can certainly set a session variable, or create a sentinel file, to say that this one-time script has executed, but since slim only runs when a request comes in, there's NO way to to detect when apache has been shut down and restarted. therefore your sentinel will STILL exist even though apache has been restarted.

Comment: If this is "something that is run by `cron`," I suggest that a web-site should have *nothing* to do with it.  The web-server userid should be `nobody` and should have no access whatsoever to `cron`. If you want to modify what happens when Apache starts up, you could modify the script that is used to start Apache. But, I would seriously question whether this is actually an appropriate time to modify a crontab.  And maybe, whether `cron` is actually an appropriate service to use for this purpose at all. There are *many* ways to invoke a process "as a batch job" and/or "periodically."

Comment: @MikeRobinson deliberately exposing my ignorance here, but can you please elaborate further on the different ways to invoke this process? My current method I know probably can be much improved on with some guidance. Also worth noting that the crontab is setup to invoke another php file, which then invokes a python file. The python installation and script file itself are independent of the Apache webapplication (by that I mean not being hosted, or tightly coupled with).